# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

Tags: mysql

i had install mysql on fedora 20 using yum install mysql mysql-server it is installed properly but i am not able to use it..
So i tired to install mysql server seprately but it giving me the same problem.

Comment: what does `sudo service mysqld status` return?

Comment: you need to start it: `systemctl start mysqld.service`

Comment: Info: error (2) means "no such file or directory". In the context of sockets, it means the program isn't running.

Comment: @mschuett It return Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  mysqld.service
mariadb.service - MariaDB database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Answer (score 0):

Please check below Command to for disk space.

## df -h

Change your directory to /

## cd /

Command to check all space consumed by / partition

## du -hs *

Problem: Your Hard disk is full

Solution: Delete some files from /var/log/ directory.